# Doubly Linked List with strings

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a doubly linked list in C by inputting strings and I want to be clear if i'm right. It's hard for me to explain so I'll just post what I have. I'm new to C so please correct me and I hope i'm right and please let me know if it's best to post my whole code.

Okay so I have my struck which looks like this:

```
 struct node
 {


  char data[100];
  struct node *previous;  // Points to the previous node
  struct node *next;   // Points out to the next node
 }*head, *last;
```

And this is a function to insert at the beginning:

```
 void insert_beginning(char words[100])
 {
  struct node *var, *temp;
  var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  var->data[100]=words[100];

  if (head==NULL)
  {
    head=var;
    head->previous=NULL;
    head->next=NULL;
    last=head;
  }
   else
   {
    temp=var;
    temp->previous=NULL;
    temp->next=head;
    head->previous=temp;
    head=temp;
   }
 }
```

and this is my main:

```
 int main()
 {
char words[100];
int i;

head=NULL;

printf("Select the choice of operation on link list");
printf("\n1.) insert at begining\n2.) insert at at\n3.) insert at middle");
printf("\n4.) delete from end\n5.) reverse the link list\n6.) display list\n7.)exit");

while(1)
{
    printf("\n\n Enter the choice of operation you want to do ");
    scanf("%d",&i);

    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            printf("Enter the value you want to insert in node ");
            scanf(" %s",&words);

            insert_beginning(words);
            display();
            break;
        }
```

I just want to be sure if these 3 parts are correct. Am I missing something?
Appreciate the help. I hope i didn't complicate anything and asked the question as needed to be asked.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by `var->data[100]=words[100];`? For copying a standard C-string, use `strcpy` or its safer bro `strncpy`!

Comment: i want to be able to insert a few names or even phrases if possible

Comment: This is a code review. I think that these kind of questions are better of in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ (not sure though)

Comment: // Bad: `var->data[100]=words[100];`.  // Better: strcpy (var->data, words);`.  See ["man strcpy"](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)

Comment: so basically i'm copying a string.. do I need to change my main as well?

Comment: [Do ***NOT*** cast the return value of `malloc()`!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: I'd advise that you still exercise caution when using `strncpy`. It isn't any safer than `strcpy`. See [stop using `strncpy` already](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/) for more info. And as that page says, also beware Microsoft's `_snprintf` function if you try using it like the C99 `snprintf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `insert_beginning` has a problem :

```
  var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  var->data[100]=words[100]
```

By these two lines you want make a copy of `words` array and put it on the node of your list :)
But you implementation is false, you just copy the 100th `char` (Which is out of bounds of the array cuz the first char begins at 0 and the last is at the 99 index) from the `words` array to the node `data` 100th char.

You have to copy all the `words` content, so you can use `strncpy` function to do it :

```
strncpy(var->data, words, 100);
```

so your function will seems like that :

```
 void insert_beginning(char words[100])
 {
  struct node *var, *temp;
  var=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  strncpy(var->data, words, 100);

  if (head==NULL)
  {
    head=var;
    head->previous=NULL;
    head->next=NULL;
    last=head;
  }
   else
   {
    temp=var;
    temp->previous=NULL;
    temp->next=head;
    head->previous=temp;
    head=temp;
   }
 }
```

Don't use `strcpy` cuz isn't a safe function against buffer overflows, use `strncpy`.

It left to you just to fix the main which i didn't understand what do u want to do it.

Comment: Thanks appreciate the answer!
Do you guys mind if I post a new question which is part 2 of my problem?